# TTL tri-state 16x4 RAM chip not working

Tags: digital-logic, ttl

I bought the 74189 TTL RAM chip and hooked it up but I can't seem to get it function.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuImL6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I hooked it all up and set the D1 to HIGH. Then I hold CE down, press WE then let go of CE. If I did this according to the datasheet then pressing CE should cause the LEDs to to show what I stored. They don't. (Yes I know the LEDs are inverted but the chips sense outputs are inverted too)

Here's the datasheet and the store page: http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/49883.pdf -- Datasheet
http://bit.ly/1oZL7hy -- Store Page

Comment: Where are the pullup resistors for your switches?

Comment: I thought pullup resistors were only necessary for CMOS.

Comment: Look at the datasheet again. Specifically, \$I_{IH}\$ on page 7. Note that the value given is positive (40 uA), which means that the external circuit must source current in order to drive the input high -- i.e., above 2.4 V. You need pullup resistors. A value like 10K on each switch should work well.

Comment: Okay I'll see what happens.

Comment: Note that this is a very old chip. They were only made in the 1970s. The only databook I have that has anything on it dates from 1976, and by 1981, it was no longer listed in any of them. Depending on how it was stored over the past 40 years, the chip you have may simply have expired from old age.

Comment: I added 10k pullup resistors on CE, WE, and D1. I didn't add anything to the other ones because I was just going to keep them at 0V until I could get the chip to work. Still doesn't work :/

Comment: Try pressing CE, pressing WE and then releasing **WE**, not *CE*. The outputs are only driven in read mode.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Was the 74189 replaced with some other 16x4 chip?  The PCjr and Tandy 1000 (late 1980s) both include some kind of 16x4 memory which can fetch a nybble every ~70ns, and the 74189 would seem perfect.

Comment: @supercat: I have no idea what you're talking about. I can't imagine what use a low-end PC would have for such a tiny RAM. Are you possibly thinking about the 16**K**x4 DRAM chips that those computers probably used? 70 ns column access time for that era sounds about right.

Comment: @DaveTweed: The PCjr and Tandy 1000 both included display modes with 2, 4, or 16 colors, and both allowed the mapping of logical colors to hardware colors to be changed on the fly.  Writing 0001nnnn to a certain I/O address would cause the display to output logical color nnnn until code write 0000xxxx; writing a value to a different address would change the hardware color that was mapped to whatever logical color was being displayed at that moment.  I don't know that the machines used the 74189, but it would have been a perfect fit for that application.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Feed the logical color generated by the display circuitry through a 4-bit 2-way mux along with the output of a register, and feed the output of that through a 74189.  Three off-the-shelf chips to get a configurable palette map.  I think the PCjr included the palette mapping within a custom display chip, but I don't know about the Tandy 1000.

Comment: @supercat: According to the [PCJr Technical Reference](https://archive.org/details/IbmPcjrTechnicalReference) (p. 2-50), the color lookup table is built into a custom chip that they refer to as the "Video Gate Array". I imagine that the Tandy 1000 might have something similar.

Comment: @DaveTweed: The Tandy 1000 might do something similar, but if one has the address decodes available, the task could be accomplished using the 74189, a six-bit register, and a 4x2 mux.  I don't think those two machines were the only ones to allow 16->16 palette mapping; the EGA card allowed 16->64 mapping, which could have been done with two 74189 chips.  In any case, there are a lot of situations where small fast RAM devices can be useful for things like address mapping [e.g. putting two such devices on a machine with a 64K address space would be an easy way to expand memory up to 1MB...

Comment: @supercat: Indeed, the [Tandy 1000 Service Manual](https://archive.org/stream/Tandy_1000_Computer_Service_Manual_1985_Tandy#page/n117/mode/1up) (p. 123) shows U76, simply labeled "Video-Array". It converts memory data into RGBI information for the video output(s).

Comment: ...by letting each 4K block of address space map to any of 256 blocks of RAM].

Comment: @supercat: Yes. The point is, by that time it was easy to incorporate such small RAMs into custom chips, so there was no reason to use ancient discrete logic. In the mid-1980s, I was designing external MMUs for M680x0 processors, and we were using 4Kx4 SRAM chips that were faster than the 74x89.

Comment: I find it curious that while a 4x4 RAM (16 bits total) is still manufactured and readily available, everything between that and larger RAMs meant for storing bulk data seems to have disappeared.  If one is using a custom ASIC, it's easy to incorporate a 16x4 RAM, but it's even easier to incorporate four NAND gates.  That doesn't mean the 74xx00 is obsolete.  Further, while adding 64 bits of RAM to an ASIC may be easy, adding 64 bits of RAM to a design using a CPLD with 36 registers would require expanding the CPLD by two size classes, at a big increase in price.

Comment: @supercat - I struggled with this problem a while back.  At first glance all of the 74xxx RAM and PROM chips were apparently made obsolete long before they actually *were* obsolete.  What actually happened is that they were renamed.  Or rather, were never consistently named in the first place, and eventually everyone stopped using the 74xxx designations.  74LS89 became a 3101A (due to many manufacturers copying Intel's naming scheme), or an 82S25, while a 74LS189 became a 27S03 (and the much more sensible 74LS219 , which was the same except it didn't have *inverting outputs*) became a 27S05.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was the equipment I was using. The wires I had bought were faulty.